# Best way to validate keys in property file in java8

Tags: java

I have a property file which I need to validate against a set of keys and values.
So that user can't provide any anonymous key or invalid value in properties file.

I have done it using reading the property file and creating a `ENUM` of all possible keys and with the help of streams I am validating each and every key from property file with that mentioned in Enum.

My Enum:

```
public enum VersionEnum {
A,
B,
C,
D

public static Stream<VersionEnum> stream() {
        return Arrays.stream(VersionEnum.values());
    }
}
```

ANd then running another loop to compare the value for each key.

I was wondering if there's any better way to accomplish this in java?

Any Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you need key-value pairs, maybe you could look into using a map?

Comment: you could have some kind of 'readMandatoryKey(String key)' method, that throws an exception if the mandatory key was not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho, the *better* approach (because a *best* one doesn't exist) is maintaining a *default* set of properties stored in another file. Having an hard-coded `Enum` sounds way too "strange" for this kind of task.

See example code, with comments (if you don't like reading, **move down** to the `Stream` solution).
For keys, we can use `Properties#keySet()`

```
// Load default/allowed properties from a resource file
final Properties allowed = new Properties();
properties.load(allowedInput);

// Load user-defined properties from a file
final Properties userDefined = new Properties();
properties.load(userDefinedInput);

// Remove all the keys from the user-defined Property
// that match with the allowed one. 
final Collection<Object> userDefinedCopy = new HashSet<>(userDefined.keySet());
userDefinedCopy.removeAll(allowed.keySet());

// If the key Set is not empty, it means the user added
// invalid or not allowed keys
if (!userDefined.isEmpty()) {
    // Error!
}
```

The same approach could be taken for values with `Properties#values()`, if the order or the association with the keys is not important.

```
final Collection<Object> allowedValues = allowed.values();
final Collection<Object> userDefinedValues = userDefined.values();
userDefinedValues.removeAll(allowedValues);

if (!userDefinedValues.isEmpty()) {
    // Error!
}
```

In this case we do not have to create an additional `Collection<T>`, as Properties is doing it for us

```
@Override
public Collection<Object> values() {
    return Collections.synchronizedCollection(map.values(), this);
}
```

---

Or even, a `Stream` solution, if the key-value association is important

```
final Properties allowed = new Properties();
// Load

final Properties userDefined = new Properties();
// Load

final long count =
    userDefined.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(e -> {
                  final Object o = allowed.get(e.getKey());

                  // If 'o' is null, the user-defined property is out of bounds.
                  // If 'o' is present ('o' represents the valid value), but it doesn't
                  // match with the user-defined value, the property is wrong

                  return o == null || !Objects.equals(o, e.getValue());
               }).count();

if (count != 0) {
   // Error!
}
```

You can play with it on Ideone.com [here](https://ideone.com/6BMf2o).

Comment: This sounds convincing, but then I have to run another loop for validating the values. Can both keys and values be validated in one iteration?

Comment: @Abhishek see updated answer, in particular, the `Stream` solution at the bottom.